# difference between having column_A in & having column_A = in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

The question comes from leetcode sql question sales analysis I (https://leetcode.com/problems/sales-analysis-i/).

The question asks for the best seller, output expected to be:

### | seller_id   |

| 1           |
| 3           |

table schema:
Sales table:

| seller_id | product_id | buyer_id | sale_date | quantity | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 2019-01-21 | 2 | 2000 |
| 1 | 2 | 2 | 2019-02-17 | 1 | 800 |
| 2 | 2 | 3 | 2019-06-02 | 1 | 800 |
| 3 | 3 | 4 | 2019-05-13 | 2 | 2800 |

I used two ways:

way 1:

```
SELECT seller_id
FROM   sales
GROUP  BY seller_id
HAVING Sum(price) IN (SELECT Max(total_sales) AS top_sales
                      FROM   (SELECT seller_id,
                                     Sum(price) AS total_sales
                              FROM   sales
                              GROUP  BY seller_id)T)
```

**output is 1,2,3**

way 2:

```
SELECT seller_id
FROM   sales
GROUP  BY seller_id
HAVING Sum(price) = (SELECT Max(total_sales) AS top_sales
                      FROM   (SELECT seller_id,
                                     Sum(price) AS total_sales
                              FROM   sales
                              GROUP  BY seller_id)T)
```

**output is 1,3**

The only differences between two queries is first one use 'IN', second one use '=', but the output is different. What's wrong with the first one?

Answer (score 0):

These are the same.  `IN` works where there are multiple rows in the subquery.  However, the `MAX()` subquery can only return one row, because it is an aggregation query with no `GROUP BY`.

This construct can be written without nested subqueries:

```
HAVING Sum(price) = (SELECT Sum(price) AS total_sales
                     FROM sales
                     GROUP BY seller_id
                     ORDER BY total_sales DESC
                     LIMIT 1
                    )
```

However, nowadays, it is better to learn how to do this with window functions.

Comment: Agree, window function works here. I am confused because I thought they are the same but the output from leetcode showed the query with `in` is wrong because it output all the results. Do you know why?

Comment: @ggggogloria . . . Do you get different results with the two queries?  They should return the same results.

Comment: @ggggogloria . . . That would occur if you had an additional `GROUP BY` in the `IN` query.